# Quotation mark in string

Tags: c#, string, quotation-marks

I have some string with variable, e.g.

```
string path = @"C:\one\filename.exe" + arguments

arguments: "-s -c -d > "somedirectory\some file.txt""
```

I've problem with redirection output to `"somedirectory\some file"`
If I put `"\""` or `char.ToString('"')` it always interprets as `\"`...not alone `"`

How should I put this `"` character into arguments?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use `\"`.

The debugger shows it as `\"`, since it shows valid string literals.
However, the actual value in the string is `"`.   (You can see this in the Text Visualizer)

In a verbatim string literal (`@"..."`), you need to use `""` instead.

Comment: This path is in *.bat file. So why it doesn't wokr from code, and if I run manualy this bat file it work correctly?

Comment: If I run from bat file this line it works
C:\one\filename.exe" -s -c -d > "somedirectory\some file.txt"
pause
but in code it doeasn't

Comment: How are you running it in code? You should use `RedirectStandardOutput` instead.

Answer (score 5):

```
var arguments =  @"-s -c -d > ""somedirectory\some file.txt""";
```

or

```
var arguments = "-s -c -d > \"somedirectory\\some file.txt\"";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string args = @"-s -c -d > ""somedirectory\some file.txt"""
```

try that.

for more information, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx